# Convergent pointwise inequality

Tags: real-analysis, pointwise-convergence

Could you please suggest a sketch of proof for this problem:

> $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) \gt a$ for every $x$.
>
> Given that $f_k(x)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)$.
> Prove that there exists a natural number $N$ such that $f_k(x) \gt a$ for every $k \gt N$.  ($i.e. x$ is fixed)

It seems very intuitive but I just can't find a rigorous way to go from the definition of poitwise limit to the conclusion.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you mean $\forall x\exists N\forall k>N\colon f_k(x)>a$ or $\exists N\forall x\forall k>N\colon f_k(x)>a$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Thanks for your response. I mean the former. I will edit the question for more clarification. x in this case is fixed in other word

Comment: With $x$ fixed, the claim amounts to: Suppose $y>a$ and $y_n\to y$. Show that there exists a natural number $N$ such that $y_k>a$ for every $k>N$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: yes, and i have reached that argument but then stucked. Could you please give me more hints please ?

Comment: Just use the def of a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be proved using the definition of pointwise convergence. For a fixed $x$,  $\exists~\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x)-\epsilon>a$. For that $\epsilon>0, ~~~\exists~N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k>N$, $|f_k(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ holds. That implies $f_k(x)>f(x)-\epsilon>a$ for all $k>N$.